# Javascript return the largest in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I have a duplicate on first part of the element I want to return the largest. I have sorted the array and it looks like:

```
var sortedMyArray = ["4ff02829-df7e/0", "4ff02829-df7e/10", "8c138c02-c139/37", "54be465f-0c03/41", "b2036e03-384f/4", "b2036e03-384f/32", "b2036e03-384f/35"];
```

My expected result is:

`["4ff02829-df7e/10", "8c138c02-c139/37", "54be465f-0c03/41",  "b2036e03-384f/35"];`

My code so far is:

```
for(var i=0;i<sortedMyArray.length;i++){
                    for (var k = i + 1; k < sortedMyArray.length; k++) {
                     if(sortedMyArray[i].split('/')[0] == sortedMyArray[k].split('/')[0]){
                          console.log('First values of element equal so remove the smallest element');

                            if(sortedMyArray[i].split('/')[1]<sortedMyArray[k].split('/')[1]){
                                sortedMyArray.splice(sortedMyArray[i],1);
                            }
                        }
                     }
                  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're array is sorted, you can just filter out each element that has a next element with the same string up to the `'/'`:

```
result = sortedMyArray.filter( function ( el, i ) {
    if ( i + 1 === sortedMyArray.length )
        return true;
    return el.split( '/' )[ 0 ] !== sortedMyArray[ i + 1 ].split( '/' )[ 0 ];
} );
```

This assumes that your array is sorted correctly, so you always want to keep the last entry with each prefix. Just in case, I suggest that you double check that your sorting behaves the way you want for cases ending in `/2` and `/10`.

Comment: `"b2036e03-384f/4"` comes before `"b2036e03-384f/32"` so the sorting algorithm looks to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

This uses Array.reduce() to put the first part of each element and the full element into an object as key/value pairs. When there's duplicate keys it compares the value after the slash to store the larger value. Then returns all the values in an array.

```
var sortedMyArray = ["4ff02829-df7e/0", "4ff02829-df7e/10", "8c138c02-c139/37", "54be465f-0c03/41", "b2036e03-384f/4", "b2036e03-384f/32", "b2036e03-384f/35"];

var reduced = Object.values(sortedMyArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const [ preSlash, postSlash ] = val.split('/');

  if (acc[preSlash]) {
    const stored = acc[preSlash].slice(acc[preSlash].indexOf('/'));
    return postSlash > stored
        ? Object.assign(acc, { [preSlash]: val })
      : acc;
  } else {
    return Object.assign(acc, { [preSlash]: val });
  }
}, {}));

console.log(Object.values(reduced));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g2rkmn9m/

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate the array with an object as the accumulator.

On each iteration split the element by the delimiter, and use the first element of the result as a property in order to either initialize it or update it to the current element.

Finally use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get an array of the unique elements.

---

[Benchmarking](http://jsbin.com/pasosa/1/edit?js,console) shows this to be faster than both of the other methods at the time of posting.

```js
var sorted = ["4ff02829-df7e/0", "4ff02829-df7e/10", "8c138c02-c139/37", "54be465f-0c03/41", "b2036e03-384f/4", "b2036e03-384f/32", "b2036e03-384f/35"];
var unique = sorted.reduce((u, e) => ((u[e.split('/')[0]] = e), u), {});
console.log(Object.values(unique));
```